# How to generate delta migration script from SQL Server to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

We have already migrated a database from SQL server to MySQL using the MySQL work bench.
But we have customers using SQL Server database still.How can i prepare the delta migration scripts from SQL Server to MySQL and run those scripts on my MySQL database?

Thanks in advance,

Ravi Kumar

Comment: You could manage your schema migration with e.g. Liquibase which is able to do this is in a (largely) DBMS independent manner.

Comment: our requirement is to do both schema and data changes to be migrated from SQL Server to MySQL.

Comment: So you actually don't want a tool for "schema management" but a tool to do the database *migration*.

Comment: Yes exactly.Need a tool for database delta migration.